# How to extract bin numbers and percents from ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I used the `ggplot2` package to draw the following histogram. I would like to print out the bin number (and cutoff values if possible) and the percent of cohort (as you can see I used `geom_histogram` to get the percent not just the count) as a table

```
ggplot(fst_num, aes(x = b)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count../sum(..count..))*100), binwidth = 3.5)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

```
ggplot_build(p2)$data[[1]]
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: Specifically, when looking at the printout from `ggplot_build(p2)$data[[1]]` the x column shows counts for each bin, with xmin and xmax columns denoting the range for the bin.